# How can I append an inline style to add a line of text

Tags: jquery

I have loads of divs with the class "chicken" and these all have a unique inline background-image style applied to them, I want to be able to add a "@2x" to the BG image immediately before the .jpg ending - so an example would be - the div looks like this:

```
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('example.jpg');">
```

And I would like to be able to add "@2x" to make it become:

```
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('example@2x.jpg');">
```

**Note:** I have loads of divs, so the image name is always different...

e.g.

```
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('example@2x.jpg');">
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('monkey@2x.jpg');">
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('nana@2x.jpg');">
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('tin@2x.jpg');">
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('crisps@2x.jpg');">
```

So need a way to add the "@2x" before the ".jpg" on each of the divs
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this using `.each()`:

```js
$('.chicken').each(function () {
  $(this).css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image').replace(".jpg", "@2x.jpg"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('monkey.jpg');"></div>
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('donkey.jpg');"></div>
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('kitten.jpg');"></div>
<div class="chicken" style="background-image: url('lollol.jpg');"></div>
```

This effectively works:

[image: preview]

[image]